# Why doesn't boost::fusion::as_set remove duplicates from a boost::fusion::vector?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

I have:

```
auto my_vec2 = boost::fusion::make_vector(42,false,42);
auto my_set2 = boost::fusion::as_set(my_vec2);
```

and when I go to debug I was expecting my_set2 to only contain 42 and false, however it contained 42 twice. Why is this? If its a set surely the "keys" should be unique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s your responsibility:

> **Precondition:** There may be no duplicate key types.

(from [this doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/conversion/functions/as_set.html))

Comment: Ok just got one small question i forgot to ask- a set stores sorted values. If the fusion set contained different types, say an int and then a reference to an object- how would it sort the object reference, based on the memory address?

Comment: They just aren’t sorted. “Like associative sequences in MPL, and unlike associative containers in STL, Fusion associative sequences have no implied ordering relation.” (and the Fusion `set` is defined as an Associative Sequence). Confusion understandable because it works differently than STL!

Comment: Ok so my confusion is this- what is the purpose of using a set which doesn't guarantee uniqueness and doesn't sort the values? (Sorry not being ignorant, just genuinely puzzled)

Comment: Not sure? The set does seem crippled, but it may be the best they could do given the constraint that it has to support heterogeneous data types.